# What is the best way to get item from dictionary giving a couple of keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the fastest way to get an item in python dictionary giving number of keys?

I'm trying to give the user the val from a key that they typed. For example:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
```

So if they typed `Name`, the function will print `Zara`

**But if the user writes with uppercase or lowercase letters, the function will still be able to return what he is looking for.

So, if the user types: `Name`/`NaMe`/`namE`, my function will still return the val `Zara`.

Comment: You probably mean `name`/`Name`/`NaMe`/`naME`?

Comment: Furthermore please do not name variable `list`, `dict`, etc. It overwrites the reference to the `dict` class.

Comment: What should happens if the dict contains (for example) both a "Name" and a "NAME" keys ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an assumption that should make sense - *there are no keys that only differ by case sensitivity* (otherwise, your question would no longer make sense).

What you'd do is create a new dictionary with *all lowercase keys*. Correspondingly, when you are querying, lowercase the query key and index the dictionary. Here's how you'd do this.

```
In [63]: n_dict = {k.lower() : v for k, v in dct.items()}

In [64]: n_dict
Out[64]: {'age': 7, 'class': 'First', 'name': 'Zara'}
```

```
In [65]: key = 'NaMe'

In [66]: n_dict.get(key.lower())
Out[66]: 'Zara'
```

As a side note, don't use `dict` to name your variables, because `dict` is the name of a builtin, which you'd end up shadowing.

Comment: but my dictionary have keys for example like :

Comment: @user5890682 Like what?

Comment: thanks for your answer but in my case its more complicate and I only gave that example for my Q, their is any way you can help me to find a way to solve my Q?

Comment: @user5890682 I'll try and be as clear about this as possible. If your example does not accurately reproduce your actual data, _then you shouldn't use it as an example_? How about instead explaining _why_ this doesn't work, so I can modify/fix my answer as needed.

Comment: @user5890682 Your question doesn't really explain how to get to this. Perhaps you should be more explicit in your question as to what exactly you want. So far, this answers your current question.

Comment: okay,, lets say I want to get into a list some values from the dictionary ..          list1 = mydict.getitems(key1,key2,key3) ............    in case their is no key1 or key2 in my dictionary so my list will only contain 2 items

Comment: @user5890682 There is no such function as `dict.getitems`, in _any_ python version. I'm struggling to understand what your problem is. Why not just use a loop? Also, `dict.get` will return `None` if you pass it a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: I know their is no such function, im sorry for my bad English but that was just a way to try to make u understand what Im trying to accomplish. If i will use dict.get for each key(k, k.lower(), k.upper(), k.title() )so I will loop over the dictionary 4 times .. I want to do all the search over one loop

Comment: @user5890682 Is this what you want? `[n_dict.get(k.lower()) for k in keys if k.lower() in n_dict]`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`CaseInsensitiveDict`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/24092b11d74af0a766d9cc616622f38adb0044b9/requests/structures.py#L15) from the `requests` package.

Although it is in an unrelated package, you might already be using it in your project. If not, or you don't want the dependency (good to avoid), you can copy the code or use it as inspiration for your own implementation.

One advantage is that `CaseInsensitiveDict` supports the usual dictionary methods including the `in` operator:

```
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'})

>>> d.get('NAME')
'Zara'
>>> d.get('name')
'Zara'
>>> d['NaMe']
'Zara'
>>> d['NoName']
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyError: 'noname'
>>> 'NoName' in d
False
>>> 'Name' in d
True
>>> 'NAME' in d
True
```

etc.

One disadvantage is that the keys must be strings. Another is that only one case variant of each key is permitted (but that's awkward/nonsensical anyway):

```
>>> CaseInsensitiveDict({'Name': 123, 'name': 456, 'NaMe': 789})
{'NaMe': 789}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your keys all are single words with the first letter captial:

```
x = userInput.lower()
y = x.title()
print myDict[y]
```

Comment: Why are you lowercasing `x` and then calling `title`? Also, this in invalid syntax.

Comment: Lowercase x is just a sample variable name. Also yes the way I accessed the dictionary was wrong syntax I fixed it. 

First make whole string lowercase with .lower(), then make the first letter of each word in the string upper case with .title()

Comment: Alright, but I'm saying that you don't need to lowercase it first.

Comment: I did tried and change the user input to lower,upper,title but its a complexity on o(n^3) in the worst cast .. lets ask this in a different way .. get all the values with giving keys to a list or something ...... lets say I want to get into: ls = getItem(key1,key2,key3) and I will get all of those items

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use regular expressions:

```
import re
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
key = "naMe"
new_data = [b for a, b in dict.items() if re.findall('^{}$'.format(key), a, re.IGNORECASE)][0]
```

Output:

```
'Zara'
```

Comment: Seriously? You want to use regular expressions _and_ loops for a _dictionary_?